# Does Endless Space 2 has rally points?

Tags: endless-space-2

I've been playing ES2 for a while and couldn't find rally points. Googling about it, I found people saying it doesn't have rally points, I found things like [this](https://www.games2gether.com/amplitude-studios/endless-space-2/ideas/137-grouping-for-less-tedious-endgame-production), [this](https://www.games2gether.com/amplitude-studios/endless-space/forums/27-general/threads/10075-rally-points?page=1) and [this](https://www.games2gether.com/amplitude-studios/endless-space-2/forums/65-general/threads/29718-automated-ai-planet-governors?page=1). Some say it doesn't have, some of them are suggesting the idea to games2gether and it seems they are working on this, some said it will appear in some DLC. So, has rally points been implemented in some DLC?

Answer (score 1):

Endless Space 2 **do not feature** Rally Points so far.

*Rally Points were implemented in Endless Space ( the first one ) with the Disharmony DLC.*